# Error when crawl data: 'EPollReactor' object has no attribute '_handleSignals'

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl data from a list of URLs. I have already done with the code below and succeeded yesterday without any error.

But today, when I came back and ran the code again, there was an error raised: the 'EPollReactor' object has no attribute '_handleSignals'
[The detailed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0It4U.png)

Below is my code:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = df['Link']
        for index, url in enumerate(urls):
          yield scrapy.Request(url=url, meta={'Index':index,'Item': ''})

    def parse(self, response):
        Item = response.meta['Item']
        Index = response.meta['Index']
        content = ''
        for para in response.css('p::text').extract():
            Item = Item + para
        df.loc[Index,"Content"] = Item

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

I searched but I don't really understand fully about this so I can not fix the error. Could you please help me to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I got the same error with a different reactor "AsyncioSelectorReactor":

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/utils/ossignal.py", line 19, in install_shutdown_handlers
reactor._handleSignals()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'AsyncioSelectorReactor' object has no attribute '_handleSignals'`

Comment: This is definitely a bug and issue ticket raised on scrapy github repo https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/6024

Answer (score 19):

Did you reinstall scrapy? I was having the same issue today - my code that worked previously was giving the error you described. It looks like the error has to do with one of scrapy's dependencies, the Twisted package. There was a new release of the Twisted package about 4 hours ago (Version 23.8.0) that seems to have some compatibility issues with scrapy. If you pip install scrapy and allow Twisted to be installed as a dependency, it will install the new version and throw this error. I solved it by doing

```
pip install Twisted==22.10.0
```

to install the previous release of Twisted and it solved my problems.

Comment: I had almost the same error : `AttributeError: 'SelectReactor' object has no attribute '_handleSignals'` after recreating my virtualenv today. And your suggestion to downgrade twisted version resolved it, thanks. I hope twisted fixes their release so we can upgrade in the future though !

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy v. 2.10.1 - released ([release notes](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#scrapy-2-10-1-2023-08-30))
with the only following change aimed to fix this:

> Marked Twisted >= 23.8.0 as unsupported. ([issue 6024](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/6024), [issue
> 6026](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/6026))

So updating scrapy to is's latest version (for now it's 2.10.1) should solve this for now.

If project require older version of scrapy - set twisted to older version as suggested in other answer.